# Google-Analytics for Android and iOS applications

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm creating an application for android and iOS, And want to use Google Analytics. But when I am adding my project in Google Analytics, it's showing some Firebase stuff. I only want to use Google Analytics nothing else. And why it's showing Firebase on Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

Well, lots of 3rd party Google libraries are now part of Firebase. You can see on top of the site here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/mobile-implementation-guide

That it is recommended to use Firebase SDK. Probably in the near future they'll sunset the Google Analytics SDK and move everything to Firebase

Comment: You mean I won't be able to use Google Analytics till then?

Comment: I think this is a business case - Google wants to have a supreme cloud service with lots of functionalities, and maybe in the near future you will be forced to use Firebase SDK for Analytics to have the recent version of Analytics and Google Analytics SDK won't be maintained anymore

Comment: And I think you can use Firebase SDK just for Analytics - it doesn't force you to use anything else I think :)